# Ubuntu logo flickering on shut down - Ubuntu 15.04 XPS 13

Tags: 15.04, shutdown, plymouth, 4k-monitor

I have a laptop with a QHD+ screen (XPS 13 2015 9343) with Ubuntu 15.04 and kernel 4.1.3.

When I shut down the Ubuntu logo go to the top of the screen, the left of the screen then back to center.
I have no problem at startup.

The problem is related to `plymouth` so tried to run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and changing the default options but none of them work.

How can I solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing kernel 4.1.4 fixed the issue.

(Consequently it is fixed in Ubuntu 15.10).